# Magento2 Display Edit Account in a popup

Tags: magento2, admin, customer-account, edit

When a user logs into their account, they see their dashboard. Upon clicking "Edit" under Account information, instead of default functionality, where magento redirects user to

> magento.local/customer/account/edit/

and displays the edit form, i need to display the form in a modal popup

I know where to edit the form styling etc, but how can i use the same form to display in a modal popup?